# Short trip Schengen visa: Can two be combined?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am applying for a Schengen visa for a 10 day business trip in Spain + France + Germany. Spain will be the visa issuing country (being both the point of entry & the largest chunk of the trip).  All the docs etc are in place and I've had previous visas so barring any unforeseen problems I should have that visa soon.

Now after the trip is done I *may* go and visit a friend for another 3-4 days in Italy. But that isn't sure yet. But will be decided prior to entering EU. I just don't want to delay the application for the business visa for this.

Supposing I have the first visa but then want to tack on 3-4 more days  can I just apply to the Italian consulate & get another visa; thus covering the entire duration of my trip but in two separate visas?

What other options do I have?

Note, I'm not asking for ways to extend my visa *after* I have landed in EU but before the trip starts.

Its only a matter of 3-4 days but with the authorities issuing very tight date-windows the first visa may not suffice.

Comment: Once it's issued you can always send it back or make a fresh application. If you took it to a lawyer they would say to add in what you contemplate along with your original premise. So go for the extra 3 - 4 days in your original application.